# TT watch installation

Tags: compiling

I'm probably completely out of my depth as this is all new to me, but on the basis that if you don't try you never learn I have tried to install TTwatch so I can connect and upload my TomTom sports watch on Ubuntu (14.04LTS-Unity).

https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch

So I `cd` to the relevant folder and `./configure` which results in:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ar... ar
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/home/brodie/Downloads/TomTom/ttwatch-master':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
brodie@brodie-ThinkPad-T410:~/Downloads/TomTom/ttwatch-master$ ^C
```

I expect I have made several laughable errors before breakfast, but if anybody could guide a beginner through the process I would be very appreciative.

Regards,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

As first step install `build-essential` via

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and `checkinstall` via

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

More packages you're need

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

After that

```
make
```

and

```
sudo checkinstall --pkgversion $(date +"%Y%m%d")
```

`checkinstall` needs a version, which is not automatically set in this case, therefore the parameter `--pkgversion`

Comment: That's really kind thank you! I shall try to work my way through that.:)